# How to Import a cer file into the jks file

Tags: ssl

I create a csr file and I send that file to my certificate team, they gave the chain cer(Internal singed certificate) file, I try to receive the cer file using the Ikeyman, but it's not allow me to receive, I used the keytool command

keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias dev -file test.cer -keystore key.jks

It's add the certificate into the signer area, but it's should be in personal section.

Could anybody can help me how to add a cer chain certificate into the JKS personal section.

Comment: What do you mean by "personal section"? A JKS file doesn't have sections, it just has one or more entries. There are two types of entry: privateKeyEntry and trustedCert. Each is identified by an "alias". If you have a privateKey entry (which you must to generate a CSR), and you receive a cert or chain for that key (which you use a CSR to get), and you want to use that cert chain for things like SSL, you need to "import" that cert chain (file) *to that privateKey entry*.

Comment: Thanks Dave,I try to import the cer file into jks, after I run the keytool command(keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias dev -file test.cer -keystore key.jks) I opened my jks in Ikeyman and see where the certificate is added , it's added on the singer certificate, but It should be on personal certificate. I need to use the same JKS file where i create the csr file to import this cer file or i can use any JKS

Answer (score 0):

Your terminology is still nonstandard and unclear so I'll lay out the basics and you identify where your problem is.

**To use your "own" certificate**, that is a certificate for a privatekey that belongs to you, in Java with the basic/normal keystore, you need to have **all in one privateKey entry** in a JKS file:

- your privatekey *and*
- the certificate that binds your publickey to you, (normally) issued to you by a CA (Certificate Authority), formally called an "end-entity" cert, *and*
- possibly but rarely none, usually one, or sometimes a few other certificate(s) identifying one or more CAs, needed to form a verification "chain" from your EE cert to a trusted CA "root" or "anchor" cert. These certs are officially called "intermediate" certs, but since they are used to form a chain they are often called "chain" certs.

And to avoid spurious errors you must also have the relevant **root/anchor cert in your truststore** which defaults to `JRE/lib/security/cacerts` although that can be modified. If your cert is issued by a well-known CA such as Verisign or GoDaddy using one of their roots, those roots are included in Java when it is installed unless you (or someone like your admin) has deliberately removed them. If your cert is issued by an independent private CA (such as a CA run by the business or government agency you work for) its root should be installed in your Java; this may have been done already (perhaps by your admin(s) or by you in the past) or you may need to do it now.

This allows you use the cert (AND key, which is needed to implement the protocols) to prove your identity in applications such as an SSL/TLS client (or server using PFS) or sending signed email, or to decrypt data PK-encrypted to you such as an SSL/TLS server or receiving encrypted email.

The **direct way to do this** is to import a file containing your new EE cert and the chain cert(s), either just a PEM sequence or `p7b` format, into the **same privateKey entry** you used to generated the CSR; that means the same JKS file *and* the same entry, specified with `-alias` or possibly defaulted to `mykey`. You *can* instead use a copy of the JKS, or another JKS that contains a copy of the privateKey entry (possibly in addition to other entries and possibly renamed) but doing things like that you can easily confuse yourself. If you do this step right, `keytool` should say `Certificate reply was installed in keystore` NOT `Certificate was added to keystore`.

If you don't have and can't get all the certs -- your EE cert and the chain cert(s) -- in one file suitable for the above, you must follow a slightly more complicated procedure:

- import the chain cert(s), if multiple one at a time from the top down, to trustedCert entries in your keystore (or optionally your `cacerts` instead, but that's usually a bad idea) using *different* and unique alias(es) not the privateKey alias; this step(s) should say `Certificate was added to keystore`.
- *then* import your EE cert to the privateKey entry (alias). `keytool` will add the chain certs to the privateKey entry. This is called building the chain, and if you did it wrong you'll get an error about "Failed to establish chain". This step should say `Certificate reply was installed in keystore`.